# What is the proper way to stub dependencies when unit testing in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, sinon

I am migrating a set of Firebase Cloud Functions from Javascript to Typescript. With JS I was able to unit test with mocha, chai, and sinon and stub out various database dependencies for testing. With TS I am running into problems and unexpected behavior I don't understand.

The pattern is something like:
`mainFunction` calls `helperFunction` which calls `nestedHelperFunction`.

I want to stub or spy on `nestedHelperFunction` in my tests when I call `mainFunction` with some test data.

`mainFunction` is in an `index.ts` and `helperFunction` and `nestedHelperFunction` are in something like a `utils.ts` file.

*Example of odd behavior*

```js
// index.ts
import * as utils from './utils';


export async function mainFunction() {
    console.log('Starting mainFunction...');

    const promiseResults = await Promise.all([
        Promise.resolve('One'),
        utils.helperFunction(),
        Promise.resolve('Three'),
    ]);

    console.log(promiseResults);
    return 1;
}
```

```js
// utils.ts
export async function helperFunction() {
    const newString = await nestedHelperFunction();
    return 'helperFunction Result | ' + newString;
}

export async function nestedHelperFunction() {
    return '***Nested***';
}
```

Test file

```js
//index.test.ts
import * as myFunctions from '../index';
import * as utils from '../utils';
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import * as chai from 'chai';

const expect = chai.expect;


describe("Test Suite", () => {

    let functionSpy: sinon.SinonStub;

    beforeEach(() => {
        functionSpy = sinon.stub(utils, 'helperFunction');
        functionSpy.returns(Promise.resolve('Stubbed Function Results!'))
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        functionSpy.restore();
    });

    it('should resolve and call the correct functions.', async () => {
        const returnValue = await myFunctions.mainFunction();

        expect(returnValue).to.equal(1);
        expect(functionSpy.callCount).to.equal(1);
    })
})
```

**Output:**
Tests pass and I get : `[ 'One', 'Stubbed Function Results!', 'Three' ]`

However, If I try to stub the `nestedHelperFunction` it does not work.

```js
// index.test.js
import * as myFunctions from '../index';
import * as utils from '../utils';
import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import * as chai from 'chai';

const expect = chai.expect;


describe("Test Suite", () => {

    let functionSpy: sinon.SinonStub;

    beforeEach(() => {
        functionSpy = sinon.stub(utils, 'nestedHelperFunction'); // Changed
        functionSpy.returns(Promise.resolve('Stubbed Function Results!'))
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        functionSpy.restore();
    });

    it('should resolve and call the correct functions.', async () => {
        const returnValue = await myFunctions.mainFunction();

        expect(returnValue).to.equal(1);
        expect(functionSpy.callCount).to.equal(1);
    })
})
```

**Output**
Test fails and I get unmodified output: `[ 'One', 'helperFunction Result | ***Nested***', 'Three' ]`

Why does it not work when stubbing `nestedHelperFunction` but works for  `helperFunction`?

*Working Example*

Something that works, but I don't understand why, is within `utils.ts` creating `helperFunction` and `nestedHelperFunction` as methods on a class instead of 'top level' functions.

```js
// utils.ts

export class Utils {
    static async helperFunction(): Promise<string> {
        const newString = await this.nestedHelperFunction();
        return 'helperFunction Result | ' + newString;
    }

    static async nestedHelperFunction (): Promise<string> {
        return '***Nested Output***';
    }
}
```

Tests File

```js
// index.test.ts
import {mainFunction} from '../index';
import {Utils} from '../utils';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import * as chai from 'chai';

const expect = chai.expect;


describe("Test Suite", () => {

    let functionSpy: sinon.SinonStub;

    beforeEach(() => {
        functionSpy = sinon.stub(Utils, 'nestedHelperFunction');
        functionSpy.returns(Promise.resolve('Stubbed Function Results!'));
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        functionSpy.restore();
    });

    it('should resolve and call the correct functions.', async () => {
        const returnValue = await mainFunction();

        expect(returnValue).to.equal(1);
        expect(functionSpy.callCount).to.equal(1);
    })
})
```

```js
// index.ts
import {Utils} from './utils';

export async function mainFunction() {
    console.log('Starting mainFunction...');

    const promiseResults = await Promise.all([
        Promise.resolve('One'),
        Utils.helperFunction(),
        Promise.resolve('Three'),
    ]);

    console.log(promiseResults);
    return 1;
}
```

**Output**
Tests pass and I get the desired/expect output: `[ 'One',
  'helperFunction Result | Stubbed Function Results!',
  'Three' ]`

Material I've read suggests to me something going on with importing es6 modules or how Typescript compiles and can change the names of imported items. In Javascript I was using Rewire to set stubs, some were private functions, but I had issues with that in Typescript.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that it has to do with the imports: if you look at the [generated code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noEmitHelpers=true&target=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAQwM4E8B2BjOAzArpmASwjTgAtgAbMYKAMXwyJIAoBKOAbwFgAoOAXAwkk8NMADuAZRhRCaAOZwAvIgkJCY4KOAATABJUa9RszTsA3H0FwowGLiikA5BWq0GBYqQBK23JTwAD5wznAA1HDi0rLyCla8AL58fKCQsIiomDim3lHaMHqG7iZerBw8-IJ2Dk6hAFSNAHIFeo31zgnJvEA), you see that within `util.ts`, the call to `nestedHelperFunction` is a direct reference to the local function (i.e. `nestedHelperFunction()`, not something like `util.nestedHelperFunction()`).

Your stub is currently only replacing the reference on the module object (`util.nestedHelperFunction`), not the local one.

You'll indeed need to use something like [Rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) to stub it out.

---

You mentioned you have issues with Rewire and TS. I recently experimented a bit with that too, and it appears that the typings for it aren't working correctly (anymore?).
The main problem is that its typings don't export a namespace with the same name as the exported 'main' symbol.

As a temporary workaround (until the ['official' typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/rewire/index.d.ts) are fixed), you can save the following to `rewire.d.ts`:

```js
declare module "rewire" {
    // Type definitions for rewire 2.5
    // Project: https://github.com/jhnns/rewire
    // Definitions by: Borislav Zhivkov <https://github.com/borislavjivkov>
    //                 Federico Caselli <https://github.com/CaselIT>
    // Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
    // TypeScript Version: 2.3

    namespace rewire {
        interface RewiredModule {
            /**
             * Takes all enumerable keys of obj as variable names and sets the values respectively. Returns a function which can be called to revert the change.
             */
            __set__(obj: { [variable: string]: any }): () => void;
            /**
             * Sets the internal variable name to the given value. Returns a function which can be called to revert the change.
             */
            __set__(name: string, value: any): () => void;
            /**
             * Returns the private variable with the given name.
             */
            __get__<T = any>(name: string): T;
            /**
             * Returns a function which - when being called - sets obj, executes the given callback and reverts obj. If callback returns a promise, obj is only reverted after
             * the promise has been resolved or rejected. For your convenience the returned function passes the received promise through.
             */
            __with__(obj: { [variable: string]: any }): (callback: () => any) => any;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a rewired version of the module found at filename. Use rewire() exactly like require().
     */
    function rewire<T = { [key: string]: any }>(filename: string): rewire.RewiredModule & T;
    export = rewire;
}
```

Then (with your unmodified `utils.ts` and `index.ts`) use the following `index.tests.ts`:

```js
import rewire = require("rewire");

import * as sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect } from 'chai';

const myFunctions = rewire<typeof import("../index")>("../index");
const utils = rewire<typeof import("../utils")>("../utils");

describe("Test Suite", () => {

    let functionSpy: sinon.SinonStub;
    let restoreRewires: Array<() => void>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        restoreRewires = [];
        functionSpy = sinon.stub();
        functionSpy.returns(Promise.resolve('Stubbed Function Results!'))
        restoreRewires.push(
            utils.__set__("nestedHelperFunction", functionSpy),
            myFunctions.__set__("utils", utils),
        );
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        restoreRewires.forEach(restore => restore());
    });

    it('should resolve and call the correct functions.', async () => {
        const returnValue = await myFunctions.mainFunction();

        expect(returnValue).to.equal(1);
        expect(functionSpy.callCount).to.equal(1);
    });
});
```

This outputs exactly what you wanted:

```
  Test Suite
Starting mainFunction...
[ 'One',
  'helperFunction Result | Stubbed Function Results!',
  'Three' ]
    ✓ should resolve and call the correct functions.


  1 passing (31ms)
```